# Styling the adsense ad unit?

Tags: css, adsense

I've lately seen a few websites doing some styling on the google adsense ad unit. Is it not against the TOS? I've seen Kotaku do it on few of their posts too.

Check this [website](http://gamercrave.com/walkthrough-wednesday-god-of-war-iii-hints-and-tips/2221/) (below the article) there are also using it.

If not could you point me in the right direction how it is suppose to be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the help information for Google's AdSense program: [https://www.google.com/adsense/support/](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/?hl=en&sourceid=aso&subid=ww-en-et-storefrontEN_v2_HCFooterLink&medium=link)

Taking a brief look, it appears as if you can control some of the look and feel of the generated ads through Google's AdSense management interface. However according to [`Newbie Central - Learn our Program Policies` page](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81562), they state `Don't modify the AdSense code.`

> 1. Don't click on your own ads.
> 2. Don't ask others to click on your ads.
> 3. Don't include any prohibited site content, including adult content,
>      violence or excessive profanity, drugs
>      (including alcohol and tobacco), or
>      copyrighted material.
> 4. **Don't modify the AdSense code.**
> 5. Do follow our Webmaster Quality Guidelines.
> 6. Do provide a good user experience.
> 7. Don't place more than 3 ad units, 3 link units, 2 search boxes, and 3
>      referral units on any page.
> 8. Don't place images near ads in a way that may mislead users into
>      thinking that the images are
>      associated with the ads.

With a link to the [full list of policies](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=48182).